# Django unable to connect to PostgreSQL Docker container using hostname (WSL)

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm facing an issue where my Django application, running on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), can't connect to a PostgreSQL database running in a Docker container.

The error I'm getting in Django is:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
```

I'm starting the PostgreSQL container using the following Docker command:

```bash
docker run --name postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -d postgres
```

And this is my environment varaible in django:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You run `django application` in WSL and `PostgreSQL container` in host, right?

Comment: @quoc9x yes i run django in WSL, and postgres in docker container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change URL (write localhost:5432):

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you run `django application` in WSL and `PostgreSQL container` in Docker on host machine so, `django application` will can't connect with 'PostgreSQL' by `container name`.

So, you can use the host machine's loopback IP address (`127.0.0.1` or `localhost`)

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres
```

or the IP address of the host machine on the local network (view via `ipconfig` command).
Look like:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@192.168.x.x:5432/postgres
```